# history.back() doesn't work in firefox and internet explorer but it work in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox, onclick, history

I encountered an anomaly by adding a button back to the previous page on JSP:
indeed when I click on the button the values ​​of the fields that i filled will be lost
this behavior is detected on **firefoxe** and **internet explorer**, 
**on the other hand everything works well on chrome when I click on the button the values ​​that I filled are displayed correctly.**
can you help me on this point knowing that i tried the code below:

- `<button type="button" name="back" onCLick="history.back()">Retour</button>`
- `<button type="button" name="back" onCLick="window.history.go(-1)">Retour</button>`
- `<button type="button" name="back" onClick="goBack()">Retour</button>`

  function goBack() {
      window.history.back();
  }

-below the current code:

```
<button type="button" name="back" onclick="history.back()">Retour</button>
```

Wainting for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set an event handler on your button using `onclick` attribute.
It's not *onClick* or *onCLick*. You were close:

```
<button type="button" name="back" onclick="window.history.back()">Retour</button>
```

Comment: always the same anomaly that persists, I even tried: `<input type="button" value="retour" onclick="window.history.back()"/>`

Comment: `onclick="window.history.back()"` should work. Can you update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem? Ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: It works only on Google Chrome and not in Firefox and internet explorer

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved :

The server is sending "no-store" with the page, so Firefox does not store the form after you leave the page :

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public"); // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "public"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", Long.MAX_VALUE); // Proxies.
```